# Generate URL to Maps application in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, geolocation, bing-maps

I have the coordinates of the position and I would like to generate a URL / Request for Maps in Windows 8, so that on the basis of the position of the coordinates it show given position. Is this possible, and if so, do you have any ideas how to do it;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use protocol activation via [LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701480.aspx).  Check the [Uri Scheme for maps applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx) to see the various options for formatting the URI

e.g.,

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("bingmaps:?cp=40.726966~-74.006076"));
```

opens the map app centered on New York City.